# Replacing both f(a) and f(b) with f(c) (confused, please help)

Tags: functions, continuity

I came across a step in a proof which is puzzling me. The step basically makes the following claim:

If $f$ is continuous on some interval $I$, and $a,b \in I$, then there exists $c \in I$ such that
$$\frac{f(a)}{3} - \frac{f(b)}{5} = \frac{2}{15}f(c).$$

i.e. you can just replace $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ with $f(c)$. Seems logical - but wait a minute, what is the logic here actually?

Comment: Nope. Let $f(x)=x$ on $I=[3,5]$ and let $a=3$, $b=5$. Then the claim is that there exists a $c\in[3,5]$ such that $0=2c/15$.

Comment: It is wrong application of intermediate value theorem.

Comment: That seems to be false...take $f(x)=-x+1$, $a=0$, $b=1$. Then the claim is that $f$ is $5/2$ somewhere in the interval $[0, 1]$, which is not true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually that is proof of only the case $a=b,\in I$. You have to prove it $\forall a,b\in I$.

It is intermediate value theorem.

$$f(c)=\dfrac{f(a)+\lambda f(b)}{1+\lambda }$$

Geometrically, it is section formula for $y$ coordinate. There will be a point dividing $y$ coordinate in a ratio in between a continuous function. Obviously, $\lambda\ge0$ because you don't know anything about external division.

But here $\lambda$ is taken negative $-\dfrac 3 5$. Unless there is more information about function, this claim is false.

Comment: Yes I think the negative sign is the problem. If it were $\frac{f(a)}{3} + \frac{f(b)}{5} = \frac{8}{15}f(c)$ it would work, right?

Comment: @rmp251 Correct.